# numpy getting 2D arrays instead of 1D arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array (3x2).

```
my_array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
my_array.shape

(3,2)
```

then I want the average value of each row, so I just do:

```
my_average = np.mean(my_array, axis=1)
my_average.shape

(3,)
```

`my_average` is a 1D array (which makes sense) but I would like its shape to be (1,3)  (or even(3,1) so I can transpose it), in other words, a 2D array where one of the dimensions is 1.

I cannot transpose 1D arrays, they stay the same:

```
np.transpose(my_average)

array([1.5, 3.5, 5.5])
```

Of course I can create a new array and populate it with my_average

```
my_average_2 = np.array(np.transpose([my_average]))
my_average_2.shape

(3,1)
```

However this requires my_average to be passed as a list, transposed and populated into another variable.

Is there an easier where I can get the average in a vector in the corresponding direction?

So If I average through axis=0 I want a (1,3) array, if I do it through axis=1 I want a (3,1) array

Thanks

Comment: `np.mean(my_array, axis=1,keepdims=True)`?

Comment: Yes, the `keedims=True` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks